# How to change Laravel Locale from Nuxtjs with i18n module?

Tags: laravel, internationalization, nuxt.js

Please advise to change laravel locale from Nuxtjs project

My Laravel backend route:

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', 'LocaleController@index');
```

Locale middleware:

```
if ($request->header('Accept-Language')) {
        \App::setLocale($request->header('Accept-Language'));
    }

    return $next($request);
```

LocaleController:

```
App::setLocale($locale);
    return response()->json($locale, 200);
```

Nuxtjs i18n plugin:

```
app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = (oldLocale, newLocale) => {

console.log(oldLocale, newLocale)
```

}

In postman is tested and working

Answer (score 0):

I solved with one line Nuxtjs plugin:

```
app.$axios.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = newLocale;
```